# Rank of matrix in relation to number of rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra

From my linear algebra text:

“Suppose that rank $A = r$, where $A$ is a matrix with $m$ rows and $n$ columns. Then $r < m$ because the leading 1s lie in different rows, and $r < n$ because the leading 1s lie in different columns.”

This doesn't quite seem correct to me. I can see that a matrix's rank can't exceed its dimensions for the reasons given, but if $m=n$, isn't it possible that $r=m=n$? And also if $n>m$ then isn't it possible that $r=m$, and if $m>n$ then it's possible that $r=n$. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, examples for the cases you gave are:

1. Ex. for $m=n$ with $rank(A)=n=m$: $A=I_n=I_m$
2. Ex. for $m >n$ with $rank(A)=n$: $A=\begin{bmatrix} I_n \\ 0_{(m-n)\times n} \end{bmatrix}$
3. Ex. for $m < n$ with $rank(A)=m$: $A=\begin{bmatrix} I_m & 0_{m\times (n-m)} \end{bmatrix}$

where $I_k$ is an identity matrix of size $k$ and $0_{l\times h}$ is a null matrix of size $l \times h$.